# Material-UI DataGrid: Can we expand collapse each row in Material-UI DataGrid

Tags: javascript, user-interface, datagrid, material-ui

Is it possible to implement **expand-collapse** for each row using [Material-UI DataGrid](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/)?
I know that we should be able to do this using TableRow and render it manually ([Collapsible table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#collapsible-table)), but is it possible to do that in DataGrid. We want to use the out of the box superb filtering and sorting that DataGrid provides.

Thanks

[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Ad2.png)

Answer (score 8):

I think I found the answer to my own question.

It's their upcoming feature => https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/211 based on https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/group-pivot/#master-detail

Comment: It seems like the "Tree data" feature within Data grid does not support the expandable row having its own columns.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a great example but that is using the MUIDataTable.
Perhaps you could consider using that if all else fails.
[example of MUI expandable rows](https://codesandbox.io/s/19r60?file=/src/ExpandableRowTable.js)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is one one muiX 's premium feature , and it not available for free , you can buy it's license or implement it manualy.